# Find and Replace String with REGEX using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a template file I import via AJAX. This file holds tags that I want to replace with input fields. The digit in the tag helps name and ID the input field. The tags are like this:

```
{ele1}
```

This is what I found to build out the regex

```
<script language=javascript>
  var txt='{ELE1}';

  var re1='(\\{)';  // Any Single Character 1
  var re2='(ELE)';  // Word 1
  var re3='(\\d+)'; // Integer Number 1
  var re4='(\\})';  // Any Single Character 2

  var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4,["i"]);
  var m = p.exec(txt);
  if (m != null)
  {
      var c1=m[1];
      var word1=m[2];
      var int1=m[3];
      var c2=m[4];
      document.write("("+c1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+word1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+int1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+c2.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"\n");
  }
</script>
```

So how can I use JQUERY to find and replace those with

```
<input type="text" name="ele1" id="ele1" />
```

The reason I use the brackets is because of my templating engine in PHP. I have a script that takes the input fields once submitted and replaces the brackets with those inputs. So I use the same template file.

Here's a clip from the template file:

```
<p>
1. {ele7} your gift.
</p>
<p>
<b>13</b> You made all the delicate, inner parts of my body and knit me together in my mother's womb. <b>14</b> Thank you for making me so wonderfully complex! <strong>Psalm 139:13-14 NLT</strong>
</p>
```

Basically `{ele7}` would be changed to

```
<input type="text" name="ele7" id="ele7" />
```

Comment: Why are you building the regex from four different variables, instead of writing just one regex? And why do you have grouping braces around every single part?

Comment: Can you put a sample data and your desired output?

Comment: The 4 variables...thats just what some regex generator made. See my edits

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with this. It's a DOM manipulation library, not a regex engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `txt` holds the data you fetch from the template. You can do the following:

```
newcontent = txt.replace(
    /\{(ele\d+)\}/gi,
    '<input type="text" name="$1" id="$1" />'
);
```

#### EDIT

Sorry, the matched groups are referenced as `${n}` instead of `\{n}`.

Comment: @swg1cor14 Oh, it'll be `$1` and not `\1`. Sorry about that.